# Un-Defined index with $http.

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Not sure for what reason I got undefined index with my below code. I checked everything but can't find what's wrong.

```
   $http({
    url: "php/mainLoad.php",
    method: "GET",
    data: {"userId":"1"}
    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        console.log(data);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
       // $scope.status = status;
       alert(status);
    });
```

php

```
echo $_GET['userId'];
```

Comment: Emmm, strange thing, what show var_dump($_REQUEST); in general?

Comment: did you try `params: {userId:"1"}`? Or are you sure the url is returning a non-undefined data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parametere `data` on your ajax is expecting the method is `POST`, if you need to get it by `$_GET`, use `params` instead :

```
$http({
    url: "php/mainLoad.php",
    method: "GET",
    params: {"userId":"1"}   // Change to `params` from `data`.
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

    console.log(data);
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // $scope.status = status;
    alert(status);
});
```